# Expanding button to x,y positions

Tags: android, button, resize, position, programmatically-created

Here are my two buttons: http://prntscr.com/hos2hz (Ignore the dotted line)

I want the GREEN button to expand with an animation to fill the whole of the view (highlighted in red): http://prntscr.com/hos3hm

If the answer could be programmatically, rather than XML, that would be fantastic.

I would imagine it would be something to do with expanding to its parent view, or more likely to an X,Y,Width,Height position, but I'm not quite sure.

All help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
parms.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
parms.width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

child.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

Comment: do you have any padding applied to parent? or margin to the child? If yes try removing those.

Comment: I had a top margin of 30dp, however I removed it and the button still only expands like it did in the original picture, except a little bit more shifted upwards because the margin is gone.

I remember seeing a post a while back which I know had a neat piece of code that code do an action over time with a smooth transition effect (i.e. Moving the position of a button smoothly along the X,Y axis over the time duration of X amount of seconds) but unfortunately, I can't remember it.

Comment: I believe the way I'm trying to remember involved this: `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root);`

Comment: btw, what type is your parent layout? Like `LinearLayout, RealtiveLayout` etc

Comment: It's in a relative layout which is inside a card view

Comment: The animation is perfect, however it expands to this: http://prntscr.com/hp5ko3

EDIT: Never mind, removing the margin at the same time of the expand works

Comment: How beginDelayedTransition() works is you have to call that method first and then make all the changes to the view properties. So on next screen update all the changed views will be animated to the new position. Since, your issue has been resolved, please mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks alot for your persistent help!